# While upgrading angular v11 to v12 getting this error JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, angular, crash, out-of-memory, heap-memory

Today I ran my script for filesystem indexing to refresh RAID files index and after 4h it crashed with following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/956M2.png)
Server is equipped with 8gb RAM.

Today I ran my script for filesystem indexing to refresh RAID files index and after 4h it crashed with following error:

getting error while upgrading angular v11 to v12 in v11 it was working fine..

My system configuration is 8 GB RAM

JavaScript heap out of memory

Today I ran my script for filesystem indexing to refresh RAID files index and after 4h it crashed with following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/956M2.png)
Server is equipped with 8gb RAM.

Today I ran my script for filesystem indexing to refresh RAID files index and after 4h it crashed with following error:

Answer (score 0):

The error message "JavaScript heap out of memory" typically indicates that the Node.js process running the Angular upgrade command has exceeded the available memory limit. This can happen when upgrading large projects or performing memory-intensive tasks.

To resolve this issue, you can try the following solutions:

Increase Node.js memory limit: You can allocate more memory to the Node.js process by using the --max-old-space-size flag when running the upgrade command. For example:

graphql

**node --max-old-space-size=4096 ./node_modules/.bin/ng update @angular/cli@12 @angular/core@12**

This command increases the memory limit to 4GB. Adjust the value as per your system's available memory.

Use a 64-bit version of Node.js: If you're using a 32-bit version of Node.js, consider switching to the 64-bit version. The 64-bit version has a larger memory address space and can handle larger projects more effectively.

Close unnecessary applications: Close any resource-intensive applications running on your system to free up memory for the upgrade process.

Split the upgrade into smaller steps: If the upgrade process is still running out of memory, you can try upgrading Angular in smaller increments. For example, upgrade from v11 to v11.1, then from v11.1 to v11.2, and so on until you reach v12.

Consider using a build tool: Instead of running the upgrade command directly, you can try using a build tool like Nx or Angular CLI with incremental updates. These tools provide better memory management and allow for smoother upgrades.

Use a machine with more memory: If possible, upgrade Angular on a machine with more available memory or allocate more memory to your current machine.

By applying these solutions, you should be able to resolve the "JavaScript heap out of memory" error and successfully upgrade Angular from v11 to v12.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 

Your answer appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). A heads-up that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

We do hope you'll continue to be a part of our community and contribute with *your own*, quality posts in the future. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved my error with this command

set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192
$env:NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192"